# Disable Swipe gesture for SideNavigationController Material Kit Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cosmicmind

I am using SideNavigationController in my app for side menu and its working fine. In my case I want to open Left View and Right View on button click.

And I am able to do that using methods

1. openLeftView()
2. openRightView()

Now, the problem is Left and Right view also open when user swipe left or right. I want to avoid the opening of left and right view on swipe/gesture. I am using Embedded framework of Material Kit and currently not able to find any property that can be set to avoid swipe/ gesture detection.

Comment: @halfer hi Halfer , could you please tell me the reason of downvote.

Comment: See the edit reason provided. Remember that everyone here is a **volunteer**, which means that it is not polite to request urgency.

Comment: ohhhhh...Sorry for this stupidity..i'll take care of it next time. Thanks Halfer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please update to the latest, and set

`SideNavigationController.enabledRightPanGesture = false`

That will disable the right pan gesture, which will disable the ability to open the rightView using the panning gesture.